# Close background processes automatically

Tags: linux, process

I use [Deepin Linux](https://www.deepin.org) and I noticed that softwares like Unity 3D, Krita, Gimp and others still running with a little of memory in background, even I close then and specify that I don't want aplications running in background (e.g. Chrome).

How can I do it automatically without installing anything, I think that's a problem with this distro, am I wrong?

I researched, but the posts that I found want the oposite, they want to continue the process opened

This case : [How to terminate a background process ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/how-to-terminate-a-background-process) looks what I'm looking for, but they close manualy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you reword your question? I'm assuming you don't want background processes to be running when you close a front-end to an application.

To see if there are any leftover processes, use this command to check:

```
sudo ps -aux | grep "unity"
```

For example, this command will check if there's any Unity-related processes running in the background. Replace `unity` with any other program name and repeat. You may omit the `sudo` prefix if your distro allows processes to be scanned without sudo permissions.

By default, Chrome runs in the background unless you uncheck "Keep Chrome open in background". Other than that, processes *should* close by their own if you terminate their front-end. If the processes stay alive, then it's a bug. You should file a bug report with the aforementioned programs' developers.

Also, to kill a program manually, issue this command (find the PID with the above command):

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

So if a program has a PID of 2831, then you'd write

```
sudo kill -9 2831
```

If you kill system services you may crash your Linux distro. Be careful! You can also try to omit the `sudo` prefix here, but many distros won't allow you to kill processes as a normal user by default.

Comment: My distro requires `sudo`. Yeah, I had checkout with `sudo ps -aux | grep "unity"` and there are some processes, I already reported to them by e-mail, facebook and their forum, but ... Thanks ( :